# Merge multiple List into single List by maintaining order of element from input list

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

Requirement:

Input: List of Integers.

List1: [1,2,3]

List2: [4,5,6]

List3: [7,8,9]

Output: [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]

Assumption: Each list will be of same size.

Here is my initial implementation which I feel is not much optimal. Is there a better way?

```
    List<Integer> one = Arrays.asList(1, 2,3);
    List<Integer> two = Arrays.asList(4, 5,6);
    List<Integer> three = Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9);
    List<Integer> out = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i< one.size(); i++){
        final int index = i;
        out.addAll(Stream.of(one, two, three)
                .collect(ArrayList::new, 
                        (listStream, item) -> listStream.add(item.get(index)), 
                        (item1, item2) -> {}));
    }
    System.out.println(out);
```

Output: [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
List<Integer> one = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> two = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6);
List<Integer> three = Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9);

List<List<Integer>> lists = Arrays.asList(one, two, three);
List<Integer> out = IntStream.range(0, one.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> lists.stream().map(list -> list.get(i)))
    .flatMap(Function.identity())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(out);
```

Output: [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]

If those lists might become long, using an iterator might be better than accessing the items using positional get, e.g.

```
List<Integer> one = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> two = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6);
List<Integer> three = Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9);

List<Iterator<Integer>> its = Stream.of(one, two, three).map(Iterable::iterator).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> out = new ArrayList<>();

while (true) {
    try {
        for (Iterator<Integer> it : its) {
            out.add(it.next());
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ignored) {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this.

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = List.of(List.of(1, 2, 3),
        List.of(4, 5, 6), List.of(7, 8, 9));

List<Integer> result = IntStream.range(0, lists.get(0).size())
        .boxed()
        .flatMap(i -> lists.stream().map(lst->lst.get(i)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result);
```

Prints

```
[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
```

But then, this also works.

```
List<Integer> result2 = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < lists.get(0).size(); i++) {
    for (List<Integer> lst : lists) {
        result2.add(lst.get(i));
    }
}

System.out.println(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as it comes to iterating multiple collections simultaneously, I prefer using `Iterator` over Stream API since you have more control.

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator1 = one.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> iterator2 = two.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> iterator3 = three.iterator();

while (iterator1.hasNext() || iterator2.hasNext() || iterator3.hasNext()) {
    if (iterator1.hasNext()) out.add(iterator1.next());
    if (iterator2.hasNext()) out.add(iterator2.next());
    if (iterator3.hasNext()) out.add(iterator3.next());
}

System.out.println(out);
```

**Pros:**

- Easy to read and maintain order.
- Safe for the variable size of the collections (although you stated it's fixed - can you really rely on that?)
- The iterators themselves can also be in another collection.

**Cons:**

- Double check for `Iterator::hasNext`.
- Is not compliant with Stream API (which is more a characteristic than a drawback).

Answer (score 0):

Another easy to understand solution:

```
IntStream.range(0, one.size())
  .mapToObj(index -> new int[]{one.get(index), two.get(index), three.get(index)})
        .forEach(x -> {System.out.print(x[0] + ", " + x[1] + ", " + x[2] + ", ");});
```